# Is there any wrong about tha static variable?

Tags: c, static

I have a problem about a program. I bet that it has to do with the fact that I use static. Here is my t.h

```
static int  cnt;

void f();
```

my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "t.h"

void main()
{
        cnt=0;
        printf("before f : cnt=%d\n",cnt);
        f();
        printf("after f : cnt=%d\n",cnt);
 }
```

and finally my f.c

```
#include "t.h"


void f()
{
        cnt++;
}
```

The printf prints cnt=0 both times. How is this possible when I do cnt++? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `C`, `static` means "Local to the module"

Take note, that the `#include` statements just pastes the header file in the including file.
therefore, you are creating two distinct symbols (happens to have the same logical name) in different modules.
`f.c` `cnt` is a different `cnt` then `main.c`

Note:
`static` in `C` has different meaning then its `C++` counterpart.
and because `C++` is `C` Compatible, `static` outside a class have the same meaning as in `C`

Edit:
In your case, you don't want a `static` you want a variable, but i guess you had problem with the Linker telling you about "ambiguous symbols".

I would suggest to declare an `extern` in the header file, and declare the actual variable in a module.

```
t.h 
  extern int cnt; // declaration of the variable cnt

main.cpp
  #include 
  #include "t.h"
  void main()
  {
     cnt=0;
     printf("before f : cnt=%d\n",cnt);
     f();
     printf("after f : cnt=%d\n",cnt);
  }

t.cpp
    #include "t.h"

    int cnt = 0; // actual definition of cnt    

    void f()
    {
        cnt++;
    }
```

Comment: Yup - check the program disassembly to see what's going on. As an editorial comment, this is the reason it's generally frowned upon to define variables in header files. Forward declarations are fine, but you don't want to confuse things!

Comment: Then what should I do in order to fix it?

Comment: Take the `static` off.

Comment: @DimK If your problem has been solved, you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define `cnt` in your header file. Instead, define it in `f.c`:

```c
#include "t.h"

int cnt = 0;
void f(){
    cnt++;
}
```

Then in `main.c`, add the following before the beginning of your `main` function:

```c
extern int cnt;
```

Comment: The `extern` keyword specifies that `cnt` has external linkage. You are objectively incorrect, @CarlNorum

Comment: Could you kindly explain the undefined reference to `cnt' error then?

Comment: Whoops, `cnt` shouldn't be static. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Data should not be defined in the header files.

In your example you will create a separate copy of that static variable in every compilation module which includes this `.h` file.